# Do Golems and Lava Hounds return to the Clan Castle if Golmites or Lava Pups survive?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If your clan castle troops survive an attack they will return to your clan castle at full health. Do Golemites and Lava pups count as a Golem or Lava Hound surviving?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Clash of Clans wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clash_of_Clans_Wiki):

> If you have a Golem in your Clan Castle, and it splits into Golemites during a defense, it will become a Golem again after the defense if at least one Golemite survives the battle.
>
> ([Golemite Page](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Golem/Golemite))

So Golemites will return as Golems if at least one survives.

I could not find any sources for lava pups, however I assume they would behave similarly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was changed at the last update or not, but I just got attacked with a golem in CC. It was alive at the end of the raid in the form of golemites and NOPE. The golem will not be in your CC.

I'm not sure what can really pass as proof, but as soon as I saw it I took screenshots:

See Golemite above archers in the first picture:
[image]

My cc is empty when getting in my village:
[image]

Comment: I think that these will be enough as proof. Nice town by the way.